# changing the colour of Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uicolor

how can I change the button colour when ever I click that button please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the action which is executed, when you click the button just add the following line:

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor randomColor];
```

This gives the button a random color everytime you click it. ;-)

Comment: run.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
it give error member'backgroundColor'in somthing not astructure or union

Comment: run isn't something which has a background color